# "undefined reference to function" error on a function in the library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to work with id3 tags with C, so I downloaded mplib and installed it.

I am trying to call this function inside mplib.h where __P is a Macro

```
extern id3_tag_list* mp_get_tag_list_from_file __P((const char* path));
```

by writing in 
    `example.c`:

```
int main() {
    char* pa = "R U MINE";
    id3_tag_list* list = mp_get_tag_list_from_file(pa);
    id3_tag *newTag = list->tag;
    printf("tag %d\n", newTag->version);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I link, I get an error:

```
example.o: In function `main':
example.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `mp_get_tag_list_from_file'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

My makefile looks like this

```
OBJECTS = example.o
target=example
misc=Makefile
cflags=-Wall -g -O0 -Werror -pedantic -std=c99

all: $(target)

$(target) : $(OBJECTS) $(misc)
    gcc $(cflags) -o $(target) $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(target)
```

I am having trouble compiling this. I believe the problem is that I am having issues with linking it to the actual `mplib.c` file where that function is actually defined, but I am not sure how to do it exactly.  I got the library from http://mplib.sourceforge.net/ and I installed it by using 'make' and 'make install'. Am I supposed to manually move the `mplib.c` file somewhere?

Comment: Try adding to `cflags` the library to be used for linking: `-l mplib`

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: I think that nnn is correct, you are not linking the library. In your main you are not showing the included header also but from the error you get I guess that mpilib.h is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build [mplib 1.0.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplib/files/mplib/mplib-1.0.3/), it creates a library `libmp.a`.  Therefore, you need to specify `-lmp` on the linker command line, and perhaps `-L /where/you/installed/it/lib` to specify the directory where the library was installed.

---

The linker command line should probably look like:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS  = -lmp

gcc $(cflags) -o $(target) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Actually, it would be better if it looked like:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

The upper-case macro `CFLAGS` is used for flags to the C compiler.  `$@` means 'the name of the current target'.  `LDFLAGS` are flags for the linker, such as where to find libraries, and `LDLIBS` contains the specification of libraries.  An option such as `-lmp` means 'look for `libmp.so` or `libmp.a` in each of the directories on the list of places searched for libraries' (to a sufficiently close approximation).  The `-L` option prefixes the following directory to the list of places searched for libraries.

Comment: #Thomas Lee
# CS 3210

OBJECTS = example.o
target=example
misc=Makefile
cflags=-Wall -g -O0 -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 

all: $(target)

$(target) : $(OBJECTS) $(misc)
 gcc $(cflags) -o $(target) $(OBJECTS) -l usr/local/lib

clean:
 rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(target)  is this good? This isn't working :(

Comment: No; it isn't good, in part because it isn't working, and in part because it is hard to read code in comments, even when it is enclosed in back-quotes.  I copied a command from your comment: `gcc $(cflags) -o $(target) $(OBJECTS) -l usr/local/lib`; when I look at it, I see that it is lower-case l. The `-l` option is used to specify the name of a library; the `-L` option is used to specify a directory where libraries are found. The `-I` option specifies where headers are found; use `-I /usr/local/include` (note the leading slash, too; it is critical). You need to add `-L /usr/local/lib -lmp`.

Comment: why -lmp? the .a file is in libmp.a, but -lmp worked somehow?

Comment: Because the linker treats an argument `-lmp` or `-l mp` as an instruction to look for library names containing the word `mp` with the prefix `lib` and either the suffix `.a` (for a static archive library) or `.so` (on many platforms; there are a variety of alternative suffixes on other platforms, such as `.sl` or `.dylib`).  It's simply the way the linker works.  It means that when you create libraries, you can use a name pattern `libxyz.a` and link with it using `-lxyz`.  It also means that if you don't use the name pattern, you have to specify the path to the library exactly.